# What is hyperspace in Stargate like?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, ftl-drive, hyperspace

In the Stargate franchise, what is hyperspace supposed to be like ? By that I mean, is the hyperspace reality/ universe like hyperspace in Babylon 5. Is it a "open" reality/ universe where ships can fly in one direction stop & fly in another direction or even park in hyperspace. 
Or do the hyperdrives in the Stargate franchise just create a tunnel or conduit type thing (maybe like transwarp, silpstream or underspace of Star Trek) through/of hyperspace that their ships than travel through.
I ask because in ["Small Victories"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Victories_(Stargate_SG-1)) Carter is on Thors ship & on his Main Viewscreen, there is a computer graphic of several Replicator ships in hyperspace & it shows them entering & exiting a tunnel looking thing.

Comment: it is an alternate dimension. these wikis might have what you need: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace  &   http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperdrive

Comment: It is really strange: Most of SG-U Destiny spends in hyperspace, and I think we learned next to nothing about the "geometry" of hyperspace then. How did they do that? With two leading characters being scientist constantly babbling science... Its a miracle.

Comment: @Himarm - as opposed to ST:TNG, SGA, and ST:DS9?

Comment: @Einer, The Destiny isn't capable of entering Hyperspace. The Destiny's FTL drive manages FTL speeds without it. Somehow.

Comment: @BrianS Well... that's kinda true. Or completely! Nonetheless: It's a miracle! Not sure what is, yet, FTL-Drive maybe, but I'm sure, it's a miracle!

Comment: @DVK SGA did it right: Relations to people on Earth were largely ignored and made room for stuff like Carter and McCay - stuff that mattered. The long gone marriage of Young and his ex, years and parsecs away - well I don't exactly need to be informed about that. [This might have nothing to do with the question at hand - realized it just now]

Comment: @Himarm My issue wasn't the interpersonal stuff, it was that they got all religious after SG1 spent over 10 years battling false gods.

Comment: @Izkata: I find your lack of faith disturbing. Also, I think General Landry summed up the view of most of the American characters on the show when he stated that just because the 'gods' SG-1 had fought were false, that didn't mean there were no real ones. *SGA* seems to have gone the same route.

Comment: How did we get from hyperspace to religions ?

Comment: @Bubba [Too much inspection](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v470/ShimmeringStar214/SG1S4/Menacejacktongue.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part all races use Ancients derived hyperdrives that open windows into "hyperspace" a dimension adjacent to normal 3 dimensional space.  While freeing the traveler from relativistic limitations it does not fully free them from detection with sufficient technology within the 3 dimensional realm.  It is possible that hyperspace is a similar realm to what the wormholes traverse, seeing that Goa'uld hyperspace communicator spheres use gates in their operation. But I don't think they are ever explicitly associated although the Attero Device used in SGA s5e10 does indicate a connection between hyperspace and the gates.

From the visual effects of the show, both ship shots and displays, hyperdrive engines open a window into an 4th or 5th dimensional space and create a corridor of 3 dimensional space for a vehicle to traverse.  Sort of a combination of the ST warp bubble and the b5 alternate dimension.  However unlike B5, gravitational effects cast by mass in 3 dimensional space don't seem to effect hyperspace.

There is another form of FTL, the slower older version Destiny uses, that does not use hyperspace, but may use some sort of space folding or warping.  It also has the effect of releasing hazardous forces/energies that have to be counteracted by the shield, a factor that hyperspace travel does not have.

One can assume that the Ancients discarded this form of hyperdrive once hyperspace drives were developed.  And as Goa'uld, Wraith, and Human hyperdrives are all based of Ancient/Anquietas hyperspace type drives they can never be better/faster than those drives until their understanding of the physics of hyperspace surpassed the Ancients.  That in mind, this is speculation, it is possible the Asgard introduced hyperdrive technology to the Ancients.  As their hyperdrives are depicted as faster than Human or Goa'uld hyperdrives.  It is something the could have brought to Alliance of Four Great Races that would make them peers to the Ancients

Comment: My impression (I don't have cites or I'd post an answer) is that ships using non-Destiny FTL drives can turn mid-flight.  Meaning that after entering FTL, the ship need not drop out at the originally intended destination.